# filtering by 1 category, that ARE NOT also in 2 or 3

Tags: mysql

So, I have an example database that identifies customers based on the level of subscription to a product. For example Sub_1 = Free Account, Sub_2 = Paid Basic, Sub_3 = Paid Premium.

Unfortunately, the database has messy data, and when a customer upgrades their subscription, instead of updating the database to reflect the new subscription, it simply adds another line to indicate their new subscription.

For example:

| Name | Subscription |
| --- | --- |
| Customer A | Sub 1 |
| Customer A | Sub 2 |
| Customer B | Sub 1 |
| Customer B | Sub 3 |
| Customer C | Sub 1 |
| Customer C | Sub 2 |
| Customer C | Sub 3 |
| Customer D | Sub 1 |

So, my question is how would I filter customers that are in Sub 1 category, that ARE NOT also in Sub_2 or Sub_3 indicating that they have NOT upgraded their subscription? The query should in theory ONLY return Customer D from this list.

If I filter by `WHERE sub = 'Sub_1'`, it will be inaccurate as it will show the ones that have upgraded due to the database not being super accurate. Seems like something simple, but I'm not an expert in SQL so any help will be welcome.

```
SELECT distinct c.Name, s.Plan

    FROM Customers c
    JOIN Subscriptions s
          ON c.id = s.customer_id
    
    WHERE s.plan = 'Sub_1'
```

Comment: You could group the table so that you get a row containing counts of the number of each kind of sub the customer has.  Then you can filter that.  I will try to make an example.

Comment: that or select where sub_1 and do a where not exists correlated query (or the equivalent left join and where test for if primary key is null) looking for sub_2 or sub_3 for that customer

Answer (score 0):

you can join to the subscriptions a SECOND time on the other Subscription criteria as a LEFT-JOIN and only include those that DO NOT have a record in the secondary join

```
SELECT distinct 
      c.Name, 
      s.Plan
   FROM 
      Subscriptions s
         JOIN Customers c
          ON s.customer_id = c.id
         LEFT JOIN Subscriptions s2
          ON s.customer_id = s2.customer_id
          AND s2.plan IN ( 'Sub_2', 'Sub_3' )
   WHERE 
          s.plan = 'Sub_1'
      AND s2.customer_id IS NULL
```

To help query optimization, I would have TWO index on the subscription table each to optimize the respective WHERE and LEFT JOIN conditions.

```
where clause would use ( plan, customer_id ) 
and 
LEFT JOIN would use ( customer_id, plan )
```

So although they have same, the order to qualify is why swapped order position for the index.

Comment: i'm having trouble making this work. i don't think I have access to adjust the index on the subscription table. Could this be why?

Comment: @rulans, the indexes would HELP, but not be required.  The query in itself should still give you what you need